# XSLT2.0 grouping based on three fields

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

```
 <passengergroup>
     <passengerList>
<passDetails>
    <route>LONDON</route>
    <lastname>RAY</lastname>
</passDetails>
<seatDetails>
    <SeatNo>1A</SeatNo>
</seatDetails>
<customervalue>AB</customervalue>
   </passengerList
     <passengerList>
<passDetails>
    <route>LONDON</route>
    <lastname>RAY</lastname>
</passDetails>
<seatDetails>
    <SeatNo>1B</SeatNo>
</seatDetails>
<customervalue>good</customervalue>

     </passengerList
<passengerList>
  <passDetails>
          <route>DELHI</route>
   <lastname>RAY</lastname>
  </passDetails>
        <seatDetails>
     <SeatNo>2C</SeatNo>
   </seatDetails>
   <customervalue>BC</customervalue>
         </passengerList>
         <passengerList>
    <passDetails>
    <route>DELHI</route>
     <lastname>RAY</lastname>
    </passDetails>
    <seatDetails>
        <SeatNo>2D</SeatNo>
    </seatDetails>
    <customervalue>okey</customervalue>

       </passengerList>
   </passengergroup>


  <xsl:for-each select="passengergroup/passengerList">
<xsl:if test="customervalue='good'
    <xsl:value-of select="route"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="customervalue"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="seatDetails/SeatNo"/>
  </for-each>

  <xsl:for-each select="passengergroup/passengerList">
        <xsl:if test="customervalue='ok'
<xsl:value-of select="route"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="customervalue"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="seatDetails/SeatNo"/>
   </for-each>

  Output
   It will produce output like this

   LONDON good 1A
   LONDON good 1B
   DELHI okey 2C
   DELHI okey 2D

      But i need the output like this 
  LONDON good 1A 1B
  DELHI okey 2C 2D
```

If 'LONDON good 'is repeating many times,it has to be printed only once.but we got to repeat the seat no like' 1A 1B 1C 1D 1F 2G and so on'.i AM using xslt2.0 AND MY OUTPUT TYPE IS text. Thing is no need to display the items many times
I tried lot ..not able to figure out the solutions please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

IMO your input xml doesn't correspond to desired output (e.g. there is only one LONDON with customervalue = good. But may be I don't understand well what you needs. But following xslt could make a job.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="passengergroup" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="passengergroup">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="passengerList" group-by="concat(passDetails/route, ' ', customervalue)">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/seatDetails/SeatNo" separator=" " />
            <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'" />
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<passengergroup>
    <passengerList>
        <passDetails>
            <route>LONDON</route>
            <lastname>RAY</lastname>
        </passDetails>
        <seatDetails>
            <SeatNo>1A</SeatNo>
        </seatDetails>
        <customervalue>good</customervalue>
    </passengerList>
    <passengerList>
        <passDetails>
            <route>LONDON</route>
            <lastname>RAY</lastname>
        </passDetails>
        <seatDetails>
            <SeatNo>1B</SeatNo>
        </seatDetails>
        <customervalue>good</customervalue>
    </passengerList>
    <passengerList>
        <passDetails>
            <route>DELHI</route>
            <lastname>RAY</lastname>
        </passDetails>
        <seatDetails>
            <SeatNo>2C</SeatNo>
        </seatDetails>
        <customervalue>BC</customervalue>
    </passengerList>
    <passengerList>
        <passDetails>
            <route>DELHI</route>
            <lastname>RAY</lastname>
        </passDetails>
        <seatDetails>
            <SeatNo>2D</SeatNo>
        </seatDetails>
        <customervalue>okey</customervalue>
    </passengerList>
</passengergroup>
```

it produces following output

```
LONDON good 1A 1B
DELHI BC 2C
DELHI okey 2D
```

Comment: Thanks a lot....You understand my requirement very well.But I didnt explain it clearly... Actually I dont know how to do concatenate fields in for-each-group. I learned it from you....Thanks a lot